# estimation of linear regression using stata

Tags: stata, linear-regression

how to estimate linear regression  using OLS with stata command 'regress', how to transform the slope of a in order to meet the following regression form
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgyHv.png)

a=E/pib

regress bc a

Comment: I don't think any one could understand this without definitions and without understanding what is your data and what are given constants, etc. In any case, if this boils down to a standard regression, then there is no programming problem to be answered. Stack Overflow is not for any question whatsoever about using software.

Comment: My problem is i want linear regression with ols if the commande regress bc a. The output will be coefficients (intercepte and slope) while the regression is expressed as follows bc=b1+ (b2-1)*a
My question after regress , the estimated i substract from b2 one

Comment: I suggest you ask a colleague with good command of English to help with your postings. From what I can understand my reply is as before: this boils down to standard regression and you are not asking a distinct programming question. Cross Validated is the SE site for statistical questions. Statalist is sympathetic to questions that mix Stata and statistics but your question would need to be better explained to get a detailed reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question seems to be about `(1-b2)`.
After `regress bc a`, your coefficient is exactly 1-b2, so if you want to get `b2`, then just subtract it from 1 .